# Thermodynamic entropy vs. quantum mechanical entropy

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, entropy

Is there a fundamental difference in the definition of entropy when considering the classical thermodynamic picture vs. the quantum mechanical picture, or are they both fundamentally equivalent?

Answer (score 1):

The thermodynamic understanding of entropy was arrived at empirically, so a top down deduction of what it means.  The statistical mechanics understanding of entropy is a bottom up approach and falls out naturally from an an understanding of the number of different microstates that can result in one macrostate.

So I guess they differ in that a thermodynamical description of entropy describes how it relates to other quantities, e.g. temperature, pressure, volume, gibbs free energy, etc. whereas the stat. mech. description of entropy just relies on understanding the various ways that particles can arrange themselves both physically and energetically in a given physical environment.  In that sense, the statistical mechanics description is more "pure" and "fundamental."